# How to make my code output six trues?

Tags: javascript

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  rule=[false,null,0,"",undefined,NaN];
  for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    dis=false;
    for(j=0;j<6;j++){
      if(arr[i]===rule[j]){dis=true;}
      break;
    }
    console.log(dis);
  }
}

bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]);
```

I want to get six true as output instead of one true and five false.
The reason is  clear that:
for the first time:false === false
result:true
for the second time:null === false
result:false
for the third time:0 === false
result:false
as the same reason until the sixth time:"" === false
result：false

How to fix my code to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your function to this:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  rule=[false,null,0,"",undefined,NaN];
  for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    dis=false;
    for(j=0;j<6;j++){
      if(arr[i]===rule[j] || isNaN(arr[i]) && isNaN(rule[j])){
        dis=true;
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log(dis);
  }
}

bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]);
```

It has two changes:

- you should break the inner loop when finding a match, and continue when not (you did it the other way around)
- you should perform a special check for `NaN` because [JavaScript considers `NaN !== NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#Testing_against_NaN)

Answer (score 1):

Update:

If I get question right, in bouncer we need to check, if there all the items persist in the list of `rules`.

In this case I'd change the function `bouncer` like this:

```
const rule = [false, null, 0, "", undefined, NaN]

function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.map((item) => {
    return rule.includes(item)
  })
}

bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""])
```

<s>What about this solution:</s>

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.map((item) => item !== NaN)
}

bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]);
```

Comment: `item !== NaN` will always be `true`.

Comment: @Teemu ah, probably the question was about existing of params in the list of rules, I didn't get it from the first look

Answer (score 0):

There is a little bug in havenchyk's answer here.
To change `arr[i]===rule[j] || isNaN(arr[i]) && isNaN(rule[j])` into `arr[i]===rule[j] || typeof(arr[i])!=="string"  && isNaN(arr[i]) && isNaN(rule[j])`.

Comment: actually, it's not my answer :)